# Policy or file to set XPages Perfomance Preoloading and Run On Server

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpinc

Someone know what's the file into Notes Client 9.01 installation where is stored the Section XPages Perfomance that is show under Preferences of client Notes?

I have need to set this information to all my client notes?
Exist a policy settings or someone know what's the file?

Tnx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes.ini:

```
 XPagesPreload=1
 XPagesPreloadDB=servername!!path/mydb.nsf/myxpage.xsp,servername!!path/anotherdb.nsf
```

[NotesDataDirectory]/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings:

```
com.ibm.xsp.rcp.perf.runon.[servername].[directories.with.dots].[database].nsf=[directory]\\[database].nsf|[servername]|host|http\://serverhttpurl
```

Where [servername] represents the common name of the server. If you miss the host, your DNS must resolve the common name.

The help [list a suggestion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_USING_POLICIES_TO_ASSIGN_MANAGED_SETTINGS_TO_NOTES_CLIENT_USERS_STEPS.html) how to update an eclipse setting, try this first.
If in doubt, some clever LotusScript eventually?

Let us know how it goes