# Xpage in Client require extension library?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I use a link like notes://DOMINO/ELITE/contacts.nsf/persons.xsp?OpenXPage in Notes Client in classic Outline. It works on client that has extension library installed, but not on the client that it has not. 
XPage is on server that has library installed and its working properly.
On the client without extension lib installed i get Error 404.

Answer (score 1):

Resources need to be available within the XPages container, which is the Notes Client. So they need to be pushed round to all Notes Clients, either manually to the relevant folder or via a Widget Catalog and policy. For best practices, see XPages Extension Library book chapter 2, pages 40 onwards. It's also covered in a whitepaper I wrote, with a section specifically aimed at admins ([the PDF is here](http://www.intec.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Maximising-the-Benefits-of-IBM-Domino-9.0.1-with-XPages.pdf)).

> XPage is on server

Unless the database has "Run server-based XPages apps directly on the server" ticked, remember that the database may be located on the server, but it's processed as if it were a local replica. Which is why @DbLookup with "" to look to current server is bad practice for XPiNC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196955/policy-or-file-to-set-xpages-perfomance-preoloading-and-run-on-server thanks @PaulStephenWithers for mentioning, wasn't aware of it :-)